# Не работает onclick на ссылке

Tags: javascript

В Ajax формируется таблица:

```
$.ajax({

    url : "/caferacer/menu/menus",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(PlaceIdJson),
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var table = $('#field');
        $('#field').empty();
        $(obj).each(function(i, menu){
            $('<tr/>').appendTo(table).append($('<td/>').text(menu.name))
            .append($('<td><a onclick="remove('+menu.id+')" class="fa fa-trash-o" />'));
        });
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('adding component failed with status: ' + status + ". "
                + errorThrown);
    }

});
```

Следуя из этого кода, вот html юзера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со скриншота видно, что атрибут к ссылке привязан и в него поступили правильные параметры.

Сама функция remove(), вообще не вызывается, но она видна в браузере в скриптах. Когда я нажимаю на ссылку, просто пропадает иконка(awesomefont icons) использую ее вместо строки, но ивент(onclick) не происходит.
Функция remove() должна удалять меню из таблицы, но когда я ставлю брейкпойнты, она даже не дебажжится так как онклик вообще не срабатывает. При нажатие на ссылку, она просто исчезает и больше никаких действий.

**Update1**

```
function remove(id){

MenuJson = {
        id:id
}

$.ajax({

    url : "/caferacer/menu/removeFromPlace",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(MenuJson),
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
        alert('deleted');
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('adding component failed with status: ' + status + ". "
                + errorThrown);
    }

   });
   }
```

В data не приходит ничего так как функция в принципе не выполняется. Она должна срабатывать на onclick, но не срабатывает.

Comment: _просто пропадает иконка,_ что за иконка пропадает? что делает функция _remove_? какой эвент не происходит?

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос, постарался не много подробней описать

Comment: добавьте в вопрос: код функции `remove` и пример, что вы получаете в data

Comment: @Grundy добавил функцию remove()

Comment: смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: @Grundy не поверите, но это первое, что я сделал, я несколько раз проверил, даже с разных браузеров, но в консоли нет ошибки при нажатии на ссылку. Вообще ничего не происходит. Как будто там стоит онклин, чтобы ссылка исчезала, когда на нее нажимаешь.

Comment: @Grundy это может быть связано с тем, что я добавил эту ссылку с помощью аппенда джиквайери ? А не прямиком на jsp?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34772/discussion-between-grundy-and-khodan-d).

Comment: @Khodan.D.: Прежде всего нужно убедиться, что `function remove(id){ ...}` объявленна как **глобольная**, т.е. вне всех других функций. Но, честно говоря, лучше все переписать начиная с формирования `tbody` и заканчивая `onclick`. Я бы порекоммендовал использовать для начала  `$('#field').click(function(e) {alert(e.target.outerHTML);})` чтобы понять, что `click` можно регистрировать на *родительский элемент* и использовать `e.target` внутри handler, чтобы узнать кликнутый `td`. `$(e.target).closest("tr")` - это кликнутая скрока и т.п. Поэтому нет необходимости в глобальной `onclick` (`remove`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в имени функции и контексте в котором она вызывается.

При инлайн обработчиках `this` указывает на элемент по которому кликнули, а так же все функции ищутся сначала в свойствах/методах этого элемента, и в данном случае вызывается функция [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), и только потом в глобальном контексте.

```js
var table = $('#field');
$('#field').empty();
$([{
    id: 1,
    name: 'sd'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'sddf'
}]).each(function(i, menu) {
    $('<tr/>').appendTo(table).append($('<td/>').text(menu.name))
        .append($('<td><a href="#" onclick="console.log(remove,this, this.remove==remove);" class="fa fa-trash-o" >Text</a>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="field">

</table>
```

Самое простое решение: переименовать функцию, например на `removeMenu`

Comment: теперь работает! спасибо )