# Как удалить input на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Дайте подсказку, как удалить инпут ?

```js
function tekst() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.className = 'one';
  input.style.position = 'absolute';
  input.style.top = 82 + 'px';
  input.style.left = 750 + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="tekst()">Текст</a>
```

Comment: Вы приложили код который добавляет input элемент. А вопрос про его удаление. Добавьте деталей для вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно у элемента вызвать метод `remove()`

**Update** Как меня поправляют, в IE у элемента нет метода `remove()`. Поэтому лучше использовать метод `removeChild` у родительского узла

```js
function addInput() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.className = 'one';
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}

function removeElement() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.one');
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
    nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addInput()">Текст</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="removeElement()">Remove</a>
```

Comment: Как раз писал то же самое :) Не дублирую....

Comment: В Internet Explorer не поддерживается, если верить MDN

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за уточнение. Исправил ответ

Comment: названия функций в inline обработчиках лучше более информативными делать. Иначе [может быть так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485484/186999)

Comment: @Grundy Принято к сведению